# SWT child shell has no buttons on Linux

Tags: java, swt

Try this example on Linux (Gnome Shell 3.8):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/ChildShellExample.htm

The Child shell will not have any buttons... only the title bar.
Even if you add any styles like SWT.DIALOG_TRIM etc.

I'm I missing somethig or is it a bug?

**Edit**
The same example on Windows shows the close button on child shell as expected

Comment: Not sure if I get your question correctly...but this example does not create any buttons at all, does it?

Comment: If you run the example on windows, the child shell will have a close button. In Linux no close button is added even if child shell is created with the SWT.DIALOG_TRIM or SWT.CLOSE or any other combination of styles

Comment: Ah, I see. Do you have any GNOME Shell Extensions enabled that could prevent the Close-Button from showing up?

Comment: ...No. However I've disabled all shell extensions, restarted gnome shell but the problem is there again.

Comment: Hmmm, unfortunately, I don't have my Linux-Installation with me right now. If I find time, I'll try to reproduce it there in the evening. From the Code, I cannot see anything wrong really. Sorry for now and good luck!

Comment: I'll fire a bug on SWT bug tracker

Comment: Here is the bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417067

Comment: Runs fine on the last redhat

Comment: @blgt: which version of GTK+ are you running?

Comment: Hm I was wrong, it's not the last. 2.16 gtk.